# Invertible sub-blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

I'm interested in invertible matrices that are built out of invertible sub-blocks.  For example, four sub-blocks from $GL_n(F)$ (i.e. the group of $n \times n$ invertible matrices over a field $F$) can be assembled into a $2n \times 2n$ matrix, which may or may not be invertible.

Suppose that a $kn \times kn$ matrix, $M$, composed of $k^2$ invertible sub-blocks is invertible.  Is it true that each sub-block of $M^{-1}$ is invertible?

I think that it is true (although I am happy to be shown otherwise), but I am having difficulty constructing a general proof.

In the case $k=1$, there is nothing to prove.

For the case $k=2$, we can use block-wise row reduction, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inversion_lemma#Blockwise_inversion).

For $k>2$, I'm stuck.  I've tried examining the maps $X \mapsto MX$ and $Y \mapsto M^{-1}Y$ where I suppose that some sub-block $B_{ij}$ of $M^{-1}$ is not invertible.  My thought was that this might tell me something about block $B_{ji}$ of $M$, but I can't seem to make any conclusions.

Any suggestions?

Note that I am mainly interested in the case where $F = \mathrm{GF}(2)$.

Comment: I just found a counter-example for the case $k=3$ using $2 \times 2$ invertible sub-blocks over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$.  I will post it below.  So, no, in general $M^{-1}$ cannot be constructed in the same way that $M$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found a counter-example using Maple.

Let the sub-blocks be the set of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$ (note that there are 6 different sub-blocks).  We use nine sub-blocks to build the following matrix:
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$M$ is invertible; here is its inverse:
$$
M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
When $M^{-1}$ is considered as a 3-by-3 array of nine sub-blocks, there are a number of sub-blocks that are not invertible (e.g. the top left corner).  So $M^{-1}$ cannot be constructed in the same way that $M$ was.

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
2 & 3 & 1
\end{array}\right)$

If I understand your question right, this is a counterexample as the upper left $2\times2$ block is not invertible (over $\mathbb{R}$, say).  This would be for $k=3$ and $n=1$.

Comment: Well this sort of works, I just realized you wanted sublocks of $M^{-1}$ to be invertible.  But for this example, $M^{-1}$ has a zero entry, so that block is not invertible.

Comment: Your example doesn't apply.  We start by fixing the size of the sub-blocks, say $2 \times 2$.  To build a $4 \times 4$ matrix, $M$, you put four sub-blocks together in a grid.  This bigger matrix $M$ may or may not be invertible.  Suppose it is.  I want to know if the four sub-blocks of $M^{-1}$ are invertible (i.e. can we similarly build $M^{-1}$ by combining four $2 \times 2$ invertible sub-blocks?).